# SQL Server Order by numeric varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, azure-sql-database

I have this query:

```
select  cast(MONTH(c.dataregistro) as VARCHAR(2)) as DATA, numberofquotesreturned, count(*) AS CountNumberQuotes from contratacao c
inner join teleportpedidocotacao tpc  on c .idcontratacao = tpc.idcontratacao
where cast(c.dataregistro as date) > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND numberofquotesreturned = 5
group by numberofquotesreturned, cast(MONTH(c.dataregistro) as VARCHAR(2)) 
order by cast(MONTH(c.dataregistro) as VARCHAR(2))
```

The results are:

```
10  5   347
2   5   112
3   5   914
4   5   786
5   5   1184
6   5   2361
7   5   2430
8   5   2184
9   5   2709
```

I want to order by the whole number on the first column and as you can see the '10' comes first. How can I fix it?

Comment: @sgeddes Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 92
Column "contratacao.DataRegistro" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the cast to `varchar`:

```
select  MONTH(c.dataregistro) as DATA, numberofquotesreturned, count(*) AS CountNumberQuotes from contratacao c
inner join teleportpedidocotacao tpc  on c .idcontratacao = tpc.idcontratacao
where cast(c.dataregistro as date) > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND numberofquotesreturned = 5
group by numberofquotesreturned, MONTH(c.dataregistro)
order by MONTH(c.dataregistro)
```

Comment: I got column "contratacao.DataRegistro" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Actually, this `cast` to `varchar` is redundant throughout the query. I've edited by post accordingly to remove it completely.

Comment: that´s it! Thanks! I was just over complicating it! Fridays!!!I´ll give you the correct answer! Cheers